# Slim + NotORM, select %Like%

Tags: php, slim

I just started to use the Slim framework + NotORM_ and need to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name LIKE '%$value%'"
```

In Slim I can select the exactly matching rows using

```
$p = $db->Users()->where('name', $value) as $p)
```

I would appreciate if someone show me the right solution to my problem

Comment: Did you tried->where('name', 'like', '%ghhh%') ???

Comment: this one doesn't work

Comment: where("name LIKE? ", "%$value%") worked

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the `like` keyword in your query with a wildcard, and add the `%` signs before and after your search term in PHP like this:

```
$p = $db->Users()->where('name like ?', "%$value%")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where_like('DataFieldName','%'Query'%')
```